# Angular: Bind NavBar partial html to controller variable

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am having issues binding my search term in my nav bar to a controller variable as it must be out of scope. In my partial navbar hmtl, I am trying to use ng-model to bind the input value to my controller variable.

my (partial hmtl) navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Title </a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-right">
      <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" align="right" ng-model="keyword">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" align="right">Submit</button>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="advanced-search.html">Advanced Search</a>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and my controller:

```
app.controller('NavBarController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

  $scope.keyword = "";


}])
```

and my view that I am including the partial html navbar in (and also trying unsuccessfully to print out the value in the search bar):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    
    <script
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    
    <script
     src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="csv-import.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="nav-bar.controller.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>
    
    <body ng-app=gcImageApp>
    <div ng-controller="NavBarController">
     <div> 
        <div ng-include src="'navbar.html'"></div>
     </div>  
      {{keyword}}
      <br>
      <br>
      <form ng-controller="CsvImportController">
       <input type="file" file-input="files" multiple />
       <button ng-click="upload()">Upload File</button>
       <li ng-repeat="file in files"> Name: {{file.name}}  &nbsp Size: {{file.size / 1000}} KB</li>
      </form>
    
     </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should just use an object.
Instead of calling it keyword, call it nav.keyword .
this will permit to share data with your ng-include, because it is two different stop that you are using

look at this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/B6ZkcDnKvrl6Y5UeFZql?p=preview

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.nav = {
    keyword: ''
  }
});
```